# Broadleaf : Not able to save shipping address using rest

Tags: rest, broadleaf-commerce

I am working with rest api of broadleaf eCommerce. I need to complete checkout process with rest api of broadleaf. I am using " /cart/checkout/payment: POST" to initiate check out process. But with this rest I am only able to save billingAddres not shippingAddress. It is required to save shippingAddres to complete checkout process. I have also tried to extend entity and wrapper class of broadleaf. But not getting success.

What should I do to save shipping address? or, Is it possible to save shippingAddress with rest api of broaleaf.

Answer (score 0):

The shipping address is bound to a chosen fulfilment group for that particular order, so you might need to use the endpoint

> /cart/fulfillment/group

to set the fulfilment group, fulfilment option and the related shipping address. 
More info on the endpoints can be found in the REST section of the broadleaf documentation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I've fired above rest, but I'm getting error 500.